# How do I handle a ReadableArray received in a React Native native module

Tags: java, react-native

I´m working on a react native app, and started recently to implement some native modules. I´m trying to handle an ArrayList in java but I am having trouble understanding how react implements ReadableArrays. I don´t really know much about java, I usually work with js.

I have the following function in java:

```
@ReactMethod
    private void serveCoffee(ReadableArray steps) {
        ArrayList<Object> recipe = steps.toArrayList();
        String listString = TextUtils.join(", ", recipe);
        Log.d("MachineDriverModule", listString);
    }
```

I then use it in React defined like this:

```
type step = {
    canister: number,
    water_volume: number,
    powder_volume: number,
    stirring_speed: number,
    water_temperature: string,
}

serveCoffee(steps: Array<step>): void;
```

I have no problem with that code, but I have no idea how to get any value inside java. The function prints as expected (two identical steps inside the array): `{canister: 1, water_volume: 1, powder_volume: 1, stirring_speed: 1, water_temperature: string}, {canister: 1, water_volume: 1, powder_volume: 1, stirring_speed: 1, water_temperature: string}`

Now, how would I get the value of canister or water_temperature of any of these?